ModuleNotFoundError 'forge.logging.config' while installing AutoGPT
I'm trying to install autoGPT (I've followed all the steps before the one I am doing now) but I cannot find out why when I run (from inside autogpt directory)
python -m autogpt

it gets me
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in run_code
  File "C:\...\AutoGPT\autogpt\autogpt\__main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import autogpt.app.cli
  File "C:\...\AutoGPT\autogpt\autogpt\app\cli.py", line 7, in <module>
    from forge.logging.config import LogFormatName
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forge.logging.config'; ' forge.logging' is not a package

What am I doing wrong? I know that package exists in that location.
I've tried to install plugins for VSCode to import package automatically but they will write the same code as the one I have

After complete Auto-GPT configuration steps,
Installing python, git, handle requirements.txt and .env file,
Am also facing this issue.
